# Deploying SQL CLR Project fails when creating assembly on database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a folder with 3 dll files in the folder on the server that I'm using to create the assembly. I tried the following code at first and got an error that said it couldn't find the system.data.datasetextensions.dll file on the server and I copied and pasted the dll from my computer to the same folder where my clr project was located and tried running the command again.

```
Create Assembly OoplesCLR from 'c:\ooplesclr\OoplesFinanceCLR.dll' with Permission_set = SAFE
GO
```

I'm now getting this error after copying the dll from my computer to the server folder

```
Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.data.datasetextensions, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.
Msg 6218, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'OoplesFinanceCLR' failed because assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions' failed verification. Check if the referenced assemblies are up-to-date and trusted (for external_access or unsafe) to execute in the database. CLR Verifier error messages if any will follow this message
[ : System.Data.DataRowComparer::get_Default][mdToken=0x6000001][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.DataRowComparer`1[TRow]::Equals][mdToken=0x6000004][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.DataRowComparer`1[TRow]::GetHashCode][mdToken=0x6000005][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.DataRowComparer`1[TRow]::.cctor][mdToken=0x6000006][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.DataRowComparer`1[TRow]::.ctor][mdToken=0x6000002][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.DataRowComparer`1[TRow]::get_Default][mdToken=0x6000003][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.DataTableExtensions::CopyToDataTable[T]][mdToken=0x6000008][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.DataTableExtensions::CopyToDataTable[T]][mdToken=0x6000009][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.DataTableExtensions::CopyToDataTable[T]][mdToken=0x600000a][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.DataTableExtensions::AsDataView[T]][mdToken=0x600000c][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.DataTableExtensions::AsEnumerable][mdToken=0x6000007][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.DataTableExtensions::AsDataView][mdToken=0x600000b][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection::System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator][mdToken=0x600000e][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection::.ctor][mdToken=0x600000d][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[TRow]::System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator][mdToken=0x600000f][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

UPDATE 1: I changed the database to trustworthy and then ran this command and I'm getting the same error:

Create Assembly DataSetExtensions from 'c:\ooplesclr\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll' with Permission_set = UNSAFE
GO

UPDATE 2: Trying to create a function on the same database to run the assembly. My user defined function is this:

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlString CalculateInfo()
{
    // first get data from the tables and then process the data
    getData();
    // Put your code here
    return new SqlString ("test");
}
```

UPDATE 3: I created the function without any warnings or errors with the following code but I can't run it because it says that no such stored procedure exists...

```
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateInfo]
( )
RETURNS NVARCHAR (MAX)
AS
 EXTERNAL NAME [OoplesCLR].[UserDefinedFunctions].[CalculateInfo]
```

UPDATE 4: Even though it is saying no such stored procedure exists, I managed to run it and I'm getting the following error:

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
```

A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "CalculateInfo": 
System.Security.HostProtectionException: Attempted to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host.

```
The protected resources (only available with full trust) were: All
The demanded resources were: Synchronization, ExternalThreading

System.Security.HostProtectionException: 
   at UserDefinedFunctions.getData()
   at UserDefinedFunctions.CalculateInfo()
```

How do I fix this exception?

Comment: Is the question out of order? I assume that the error noted in the first paragraph what you got after you copied that DLL to the folder with your SQLCLR DLL in the second paragraph, right? And what version of SQL Server will this be deployed on?

Comment: @srutzky Yes I didn't notice until now that the question got out of order. But yes you are correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, only a short list of .NET Framework libraries are "supported". You can find that list on the MSDN page for [Supported .NET Framework Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx). **System.Data.DataSetExtensions** is not one of them. That is why you got the first error.

The second thing posted is a warning, not an error. It is telling you that you can run into one or more problems that Microsoft will not care about or fix as you are doing something that is unsupported.

Run the following in the database where you are deploying the assemblies:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies sa WHERE sa.is_user_defined = 1;
```

and you should see both. Although if **System.Data.DataSetExtensions** has dependent libraries, they won't be automatically loaded because only the folder that the initial `CREATE ASSEMBLY` is pointing to will get loaded, and that is now where your DLL is being built and not the .NET Framework folder.

You might be better off loading **System.Data.DataSetExtensions** by itself in its own `CREATE ASSEMBLY` pointing to the appropriate **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework (or Framework64)** folder. Especially if you notice that the error message shows "Code size is zero", which I have only seen when trying to load the DLL from one of the **Reference Assemblies** folders.

Now, because this is an unsupported library it probably does stuff that disallow it from being loaded as `SAFE`. Since we don't have the private key info in order to go the ideal route of creating an Asymmetric Key and then a Login based on that Asymmetric Key, you have little choice but to:

- set the database you are deploying to as TRUSTWORTHY via:

  ```
  ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
  ```
- load the assembly `WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE`

Essentially:

```sql
USE [DatabaseName];

ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;

CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Data.DataSetExtensions]
FROM
   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

After that you should be able to load your assembly, though it will likely have to be set to `UNSAFE` as well.

And I would delete the copy of **System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll** that you put in your build folder.

---

For more info on SQLCLR in general, please see the series I am writing on SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (free registration required).

Comment: I ran that query and I don't see anything

Comment: I updated my question to show the changes I made and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @user3610374 I just updated to mention that issue. "Code size is zero" I believe only happens when trying to load a reference assembly and not the true assembly.

Comment: My last question is how do I run my function on the database? I'm reading an article that says to create a function for the assembly but doesn't give me an example

Comment: I was finally able to create the assembly. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to create a function on the database to be able to run the code

Comment: Are you using a SSDT Database Project? If you do a "publish" it should create the function for you.

Comment: I don't think it is a SSDT Database Project. I created a SQL CLR C# User Defined Function Project

Comment: @user3610374 Something will need to call `CREATE FUNCTION` and reference the method in the DLL. In your project properties, do you have a tab for SQLCLR?

Comment: Yes I have a tab for SQLCLR

Comment: Ok I believe I created the function successfully. I posted the command I tried above and I got no errors or warnings but it won't let me run the function because it is saying that no such stored procedure exists. I can confirm that I can see the function in the database under programmability > scalar-valued functions. I managed to run the function and I'm getting an error that I pasted above in my question details

Comment: @user3610374 Not sure what you mean by Stored Procedure as you are creating a Function. And that last error message means that your Assembly needs to be set to `UNSAFE`. I would also suggest that you do A LOT of testing, and with multiple users, since it is quite likely that you are not taking into account the shared nature of the SQLCLR environment, especially when using functionality like Synchronization and ExternalThreading. I will also put a link in my answer to a series of articles I am writing about SQLCLR.

Comment: @user3610374 not if it's currently working. But if you added as `SAFE`, just use `ALTER ASSEMBLY`.