# System.Security.HostProtectionException: Attempted to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, multithreading, sqlclr

I'm using threading in my SQLCLR Project and I'm getting the following error when I try to run my user defined function. What can I do to enable threading things such as the Parallel library and await/async in my project?

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "CalculateInfo":
>     System.Security.HostProtectionException: Attempted to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host.
>
> The protected resources (only available with full trust) were: All
>       The demanded resources were: Synchronization, ExternalThreading
>
> System.Security.HostProtectionException:
>           at UserDefinedFunctions.getData()
>           at UserDefinedFunctions.CalculateInfo()

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This error, as noted in your other question, [Deploying SQLCLR project fails when creating assembly in database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268691/577765), requires the following:

```
ALTER ASSEMBLY [AssemblyName]
   WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

For more information on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Set Premission set field value to Unrestricted.